# Using findViewById inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating a new Tab interface and for every tab I have functionality like:

```
public class ClassViewFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView classListView = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.class_view, container, false);

        classListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.classList);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

But I am getting `cannot resolve method findViewById` also at another place I am also unable to use `runOnUiThread` and getting `Error:(88, 29) error: cannot find symbol method runOnUiThread(<anonymous Runnable>)`

I understand these will work fine if my class was extended from `Activity` but it’s a tab fragment so how can I use this funcitons?

Comment: `classListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.classList);

Comment: possible duplicate of [findViewById in fragment android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment-android)   ...  What can be found by simple googling...

Comment: @Selvin yes it is. Lets vote to close it as duplicate of [findViewById in Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment)! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need

```
classListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.classList);
```

as that is the view you are concerned with

to get runOnUiThred you need to do `getActivity().runOnUiThread`

Comment: the `rootView` object is only accesbile in `onCreateView` and not in other functions inside the class?

Comment: correct if you need it else where just hold onto it globally. You could also just hold onto the item you specifically need instead of the whole view

Answer (score 5):

You need to reference findViewById using the view,

```
public class ClassViewFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView classListView = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.class_view, container, false);

        classListView = (ListView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.classList);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

For runOnUiThread is a possible duplicate of [Modifying an Android view from a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706342/modifying-an-android-view-from-a-different-thread)

use its like,

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shore explanation of `findViewById` method;

`findViewById()` method will work with the related object that your main layout is bound to. For example, In an activity, when you make a

```
setContentView(activity_main);
```

You imply that your `Activity` will retrieve its layouts from `activity_main`. So when you make a `findViewById()` in an activity, that actually means `this.findViewById()`, where `this` is your `Activity`.

So in your case, the layout `class_view` is bound to the `rootView`. But when you just write `findViewById`, it means that `this.findViewById`. And `this` is the scope you're in, which is the `Fragment` in your case. However, I don't think a Fragment has that capability. So you should refer to the `rootView` to retrieve your views.

```
rootView.findViewById()
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragments don't have a findViewById() method like Activity, so you have to call the method of the root view of the fragment.  Try doing rootView.findViewById(R.id.classList) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content_mediaplayer, container, false);
        mSeekbar = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seekBarMusic);
        return v;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rootView.findViewById(R.id.classList)` instead of `findViewById(R.id.classList)`.

**Try this:**

```
public class ClassViewFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView classListView = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.class_view, container, false);
        classListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.classList);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

findViewById must run inside onViewCreated() method

```
ListView classListView = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.class_view, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    classListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.classList);
}
```

}`